# Import and use google webfont

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

For a project, I have to use many style off a font.
Here is the link of [the google font](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aOpen+Sans)

Here is my css import

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,300,400,700);
```

What I would like to know is how can I define the font-family to display for example the "Open Sans Light 300 Italic"

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,300,400,700);
        body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        body p {
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 300; /* You specify the number you see next to the fonts to change from light to bold ie you would put 700 etc. etc. */
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand this part: "...family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,". What and how does it apply the second (400italic) font weight?

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

300/400/700 is font-weight. If you want bold font use

```
font:bold(or 700) 12px/15px "Open Sans", sans-serif
```

if you want light italic use

```
font:300 italic 12px/15px "Open Sans", sans-serif
```