# Font not showing properly in HTML page

Tags: html, css, font-family

I'm using two font family,  1. "Open sans"  2. Colvetica . I'm facing this kind of problem with these fonts.

1) I use open sans like this " font-family: 'Open Sans'; " in CSS file. It works only those computer who has open sans installed. But in mobile this is not working at all.

2) For colvetica, I used that but not working. I don't know how to to use that. I use colvetica font  file but same issue. How to use this font ?

I need opensans and colvetica in same page . like colvetica for 
 , and opensans for

Comment: Of course it's not working if you don't have the font.

Comment: Please don't add "urgent" or similar to your posts - all questions have equal priority here. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import and use google webfont](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161854/import-and-use-google-webfont)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import by Google fonts or with @font-face.

In Google fonts you can use import by HTML or CSS:

**On your HTML:**

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**On your CSS:**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

If you can't find you font on [google.com/fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts), you can create your own font face kit: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator (you can generate everything, including the css code to embed font), so not all fonts can be converted. See the path to make it in the correct url

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the fonts in the site, ether with a link to the css file online

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Or you would include the fonts into the site using `@font-face{}`

Answer (score 2):

from [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

How to host and embed font files using css

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
</style>
```

Comment: Additional to the answer of @andrew: If you only have the ttf file extension you could generate all the fonts here: [font-squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Comment: This requires you to have the actual font files in your site root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide them a way to download the font.

Put `@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans')`
at the top of your css. 
This was covered in [this question by another user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file)