# Open Sans Will Not Load On My Live Server

Tags: css

I really wanted to use this font for links to other pages, but for some reason it will just not load. It seems as though there are some fonts that load and others that do not, both of which I have downloaded locally.

```
.navBarLinks {
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}

.aboutUs {
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
top: 6vh;
left: 10%;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-size: 18rem;
color: #0e0e0e;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Have you included source for that font? If it's not installed on computer, than browser will not be able to use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font not showing properly in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610902/font-not-showing-properly-in-html-page)

Comment: Yes, the font is installed on the computer. I downloaded it from the official Google Fonts website. And unfortunately, the "Font Not Showing Properly In HTML Page" did not work.